Adding Delay in Between Changes in Driver?
I'm trying to create a blinking/flickering light effect which can be activated with a driver, and came up with this very messy driver expression which I found does work to an extent. However, I want there to be a five frame pause after the empty moves up and down to slow down the flickering effect. What would be a good way to get the delay I want, and also optimize the expression? 

